# Question related with Archimedean property and complete ordered field.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $K$ be an ordered field, in which the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) is satisfied.
Show that if every bounded increasing sequence in $K$ has a least
upper bound in $K$, then $K$ is a complete ordered field.

Comment: I don't believe that you have completely no idea. Presumably you know the definition of an ordered field, and a complete ordered field. That means you can probably guess exactly which property you need to prove that $K$ fulfills. Do you see any connection between that property and the property you're given in the problem?

Comment: On this site, we discourage posts which appear, like this, to be just homework questions. We look for more context: where did you encounter the problem? What related facts have you seen? What are your thoughts and partial attempts on the problem?

Comment: This is not [tag:set-theory]. Do not retag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, the process your professor mentions doesn't have to terminate.

Example: Take $(a_{1i})_i$ as an increasing sequence converging to $a_1 = 1$, $(a_{2i})_i$ converge to $a_2 = a_1 + \frac{1}{2^2}$ and inductively $(a_{ji})_i$ a sequence converging to $a_j = a_{j-1} + \frac{1}{j^2}$. This is a sequence you could obtain in the process for the bounded set $(0,10) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and obviously does not terminate. By some transfinite induction argument this might get fixed (someone else has to verify this).

How about you define a sequence as follows: Take $a_0 \in A$ arbitrary.

If $a_0 + 1$ is not an upper bound for $A$, then there is some $a_0 + 1 < a_1 \in A$. We continue this process and by the archemedian property we obtain some $a_n$ such that $a_n + 1$ is an upper bound for $A$. Denote this by $b_1 = a_n$.

Now repeat the process with $a_0 = b_1$ and instead of adding $1$ we add $\frac{1}{2}$ and later $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}\ldots$

This yields an increasing sequence $(b_i)_i$ with least upper bound $b$. We show that $b$ is also a least upper bound for $A$. Assume there is $a \in A$ with $a > b$. By the archemedian principle there is $n$ with $a - b > \frac{1}{n}$ or, in other words, $a > b + \frac{1}{n} > b_n + \frac{1}{n} \geq a$ by definition of $b_n$. Thus $b$ is in fact an upper bound for $A$. Now assume there is an upper bound $b'$ of $A$ with $b' < b$. Again by the archemedian principle we have $n$ such that $b' + \frac{1}{n} < b \leq b_n + \frac{1}{n}$ and thus $b' < b_n \in A$ which is again a contradiction.

Comment: I thought of this before, but the issue is $1/2,1/3,....$ is not properly defined. I know we have to prove it to be equivalent to R, but we can't assume that in the proof.

Comment: ??? I assumed nowhere it's $\mathbb{R}$ except in the counter-example.

Comment: " instead of adding 1 we add 1/2 and later 1/3,1/4 " If I understand it correctly?

Comment: It's an ordered field, thus it's prime field is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you! This is not in my book, can I ask for a reference for this to include it into my notes? is it because ordered field need to have a characteristic zero and there exist a isomorphism injection of Q into all ordered field with characteristic zero?

Comment: This is a very basic result in field theory, that characteristic zero fields $K$ have $\mathbb{Q}$ as their prime field. The injection is simply given by $1_{\mathbb{Q}} \mapsto 1_K$. and if $K$ is ordered, it's characteristic is zero.

Comment: Sorry, one last question can you explain the logic of $" b′+1/n<b≤b/n+1/n"$, I am a little confused about how do you find such a $n$

Comment: That's the archimedian principle. It says (at least that's the definition that I know) that for all $x$ there is $n$ with $n > x$. Let now $0 < x \in K$. Then $0 < \frac{1}{x} \in K$ and by the archimedian principle we have some $n$ with $n > \frac{1}{x}$. By taking the inverses we obtain $\frac{1}{n} < x$. We now use this for $x = b - b'$.

Comment: What about the second half : $b<b_n+1/n$. If such $b'$ exist, then there may exist $b_n + 1/n < b$

Comment: On a second thought, there must exist $b_n > b'$, or b won't be the lowest upper bound.

Comment: We know that $b_n + \frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for $A$. Since $b_i \in A$ for all $i$ we see that $b_n + \frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for the whole sequence $(b_i)_i$. But $b$ is the least upper bound and thus $b < b_n + \frac{1}{n}$.